# Парсер командной строки cmd.exe с помощью java

Tags: java, windows, парсер, cmd, консоль

Имеется программа - исполняемый файл .exe, которая выполняется на Windows. Программа выводит результат проделанных действий в консоль cmd.exe, каждая строка результат выполненного действия.

**Как с помощью java приложения считывать, что происходить в консоли стороннего exe приложения? Какой инструмент использовать для этого?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если *стороннее приложение* запустила сама java-программа, то она может получить вывод этого приложения и читать из него:

```
import java.io.*;

public class PipeProcess {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] command = { "someprogram.exe", "some-argument" };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        process.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println("Output: " + s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, впринципе это думаю мне подойдёт, попробую запускать exe файл с помощью java. Но, на будущее, если стороннее приложение запущено самостоятельно существуют ли варианты чтения? Ведь человек может читать, как это автоматизировать? )

Comment: На Java и под Windows точно нет.

Comment: [Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его решением.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)